# Error is appearing while I'm trying to execute the flutter app

Tags: android, windows, gradle, flutter

I've tried to run a flutter app and this error always keeps showing. I created the app with the command `flutter create project_name`. I added the path to the android sdk and added the ANDROID_HOME in environment variables.

The error:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\project_f\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\project_f\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Conversion = 'M'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
  Command: C:\project_f\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```